# Angular/HTML input datetime-local with forms and Angular date

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms, html-input

In my Angular application, I want a user to select a date and a time for an appointment, I am trying to use the

```
<input matInput type="datetime-local"...>
```

element for this. But this control needs to be bound to a form, so I created a form

```
public form: FormGroup;

constructor(_formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = _formbuilder.group({
    datetime: new Date()
  });
}
```

and I wrap the `input` in this form such that it becomes

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input matInput type="datetime-local" formControlName="datetime">
</form>
```

This works fine as the date time is inserted in my form but the initial value is simply blank
[image]

This remains blank until i start changing it. I assume because the input requires a string? I'd rather give it a date but even giving it a string

```
constructor(_formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
   this.form = _formbuilder.group({
     datetime: new Date().toDateString()
   });
}
```

yields the exact same result. So how can I bind it to a Typscript Date object and start displaying it with an initial value?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it working in this way (Angular 2+, Reactive Forms):

my.component.html:

```
<input type="datetime-local" formControlName="myDateTime">
```

my.component.ts:

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
myForm: FormGroup;
now: Date = new Date();

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      myDateTime: [formatDate(this.now, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm', 'en'), [Validators.required]]
    });
}

//..
}
```

The most critical part to notice is the date pattern formatted inside *formatDate()* function that should be compliant with HTML 5 specifications (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local).

This made the difference, in my case.

Answer (score 1):

HTML datetime-local input required 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm' format, but have given date object.

So you use Angular date pipe as another way to convert it.

```
  import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private datePipe: DatePipe,
    ) {
      this.form = _formbuilder.group({
        datetime: this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm')
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use any of the formats described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#local_date_and_time_strings).